# Spring: Model not generating ID values, and not adding anything into H2 database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have a println statement in my @PostMapping controller, and every time I try to submit something, it comes back with either Null or 0 (depending on the data type I tried) for the ID value, and nothing's getting put into the database. I'm also not sure how to initialize/setup the DB... Other than the model User.Java file, is there something I need to do?

This is what I have for my **model** (not including the get/set/toString's)
Also, I'd like to note that I've been researching this a bunch, and **I did try every GenerationType, and all had the same result.**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String scroll;
    private String date;

    User() {
        this.date = LocalDate.now().toString();
    }

    User(String name, String scroll) {
        this.name = name;
        this.scroll = scroll;
        this.date = LocalDate.now().toString();
    }
```

This is my **repo**:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

My **application.properties** (the bottom 3 I added in from past projects to see if they might help initialize the DB, but they didn't):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

spring.devtools.restart.log-condition-evaluation-delta=false
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

And this is the relevant block from my **controller** (which I doubt is the issue because the info entered in the form is coming through & printing fine):

```
    @PostMapping("/found")
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        System.out.println(user);
        return "finders";
    }
```

And finally, just for good measure, here's my **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>site</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>site</name>
    <description>The Legendary Phoenix</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So what do you guys think? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Tried:

- Different Generation Types
- Various application.properties
- Deleting DB file and restarting it

Experiencing:

- Nothing getting added to DB
- ID not being generated

Comment: If nothing is in the db - that is your bigger issue and why you aren't seeing IDs being generated. Identity only assigns ID values when the insert statements are issued to the db, which only occurs when the EntityManager context is synchronized to the db (flushed or the transaction commits). How are you managing the transaction contexts around your calls?

Comment: Chris, I was thinking the same thing as far as it not generating from an empty DB. That's why I asked about if there might be something I was missing as far as initializing the DB.

What do you mean by transaction contexts though? If it's not in the code I posted, then I'm guessing that I'm probably not managing them?

Comment: Yep! You'll want to look at the tutorials, but generally you demarcate which method start transactions, which can use a running transaction, and which need to be run entirely outside of transactions with the @Transaction annotation in containers/Spring